# node-sass installation error: couldn't find package "error-ex"

Tags: yarnpkg, node-sass, sass-loader

When I tried to install `node-sass` as a dependency for `sass-loader` for a react app using yarn, I got the following error:

```
yarn add v1.22.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
error Couldn't find package "error-ex" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I already have latest versions of yarn and npm. The same command seemed to work a few days back. But right now not working. Now I have to switch over to `dart-sass` instead of `node-sass`. I don't usually specify the version when installing dependencies. Does this error have anything to do with that?

Here are my dependencies in case:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

Comment: There are some errors going on in the npm registry. 
You can check the status here: https://status.npmjs.org/, it should be solved soon.

Comment: thanks @Geku. I ran yarn add today and it worked.

Comment: Good to know! It worked for me too :)

Answer (score 3):

try this in the terminal `npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry`